# Databinding a WinForms ComboBox requires user-interaction twice

Tags: winforms, data-binding

I have a ComboBox (DropDownList style) in a Windows Form which has a data-source set to a BindingList, and has the SelectedValue property bound to a viewmodel's property.

**Note that the binding is set to `OnPropertyChanged` rather than `OnValidate`**, this is because when using `OnValidate` the control will not necessarily update the ViewModel if the form is closed or loses focus (but the control still thinks it has focus. On the Compact Framework there is no way to 'force validation' so I have to use `OnPropertyChanged`.

There's a problem which is reproducible on both desktop Windows Forms and Smart Device Windows Forms: when attempting to select or set the current item in the combobox (using the mouse or keyboard) the value will not "stick" until it is set twice - that is, you need to select the same item twice before the combobox's value will change.

There are no exceptions thrown (even caught exceptions) and no diagnostics reports to speak of.

I don't think this is a bug in the framework, and it's interesting how it happens on both Desktop and Compact Framework.

Here's my code:

#### Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

    private ViewModel _vm;

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.bindingSource1.Add( _vm = new ViewModel() );
    }
}
```

#### Form1.Designer.cs (relevant lines)

```
        // 
        // bindingSource1
        // 
        this.bindingSource1.DataSource = typeof( WinForms.Shared.ViewModel );
        // 
        // comboBox1
        // 
        this.comboBox1.DataBindings.Add( new System.Windows.Forms.Binding( "SelectedValue", this.bindingSource1, "SelectedSomeTypeId", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged ) );
        this.comboBox1.DataSource = this.someTypeListBindingSource;
        this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "DisplayText";
        this.comboBox1.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        this.comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.comboBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point( 12, 27 );
        this.comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1";
        this.comboBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size( 182, 21 );
        this.comboBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
        // 
        // someTypeListBindingSource
        // 
        this.someTypeListBindingSource.DataMember = "SomeTypeList";
        this.someTypeListBindingSource.DataSource = this.bindingSource1;
```

#### ViewModel.cs

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public ViewModel() {

        this.SomeTypeList = new BindingList<SomeType>();

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            this.SomeTypeList.Add( new SomeType() {
                Id = i + 1,
                Name = "Foo" + ((Char)( 'a' + i )).ToString()
            } );
        }

        this.SelectedSomeTypeId = 2;
    }

    public BindingList<SomeType> SomeTypeList { get; private set; }


    private Int64 _selectedSomeTypeId;
    public Int64 SelectedSomeTypeId {
        get { return _selectedSomeTypeId; }
        set {
            if( _selectedSomeTypeId != value ) {
                _selectedSomeTypeId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedSomeTypeId");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName) {

        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if( handler != null ) handler( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName) );
    }
}

public class SomeType {

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public Int64 Id { get; set; }

    public String DisplayText {
        get { return String.Format("{0} - {1}", this.Id, this.Name ); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have never found the 'right' way around this issue and generally use one of two ways to make things work:

- **Direct**: Just bypass the binding mechanism for this one entry

  `combo1.SelectedIndexChanged += (s,e) _viewModel.Item = combo1.SelectedItem;`
- **Generic Binding**: Make a custom ComboBox and override the OnSelectedIndexChanged event to force the binding update.

  `public class BoundComboBox : ComboBox
  {
      protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
      {
        var binding = this.DataBindings["SelectedItem"];
        if( binding != null )
            binding.WriteValue();
        base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e);
     }
  }`